# Google Analytics - Track Custom URL Params

Tags: google-analytics, uri, analytics

I have a lot of data in Analytics I would like to do some research on.

Basically I have a page `site.com/products/results` which has variables like: `?na=1&soc=triple`

I would like to track what the stats of `'na'` is on the pages. It varies from 1-10 and I'm try to get % on which is the most popular.

Answer (score 0):

If you can somehow extract the *value* from the url you could use something like this:

```js
ga('set', 'na', value);
```

This requires a custom definition for 'na' to be set up in the Administration -> Property -> Custom Definitions section of your google analytics account.